# Robotlegs Vs Parsley

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, dependency-injection, robotlegs, parsley

I am planning to start a new project in as3 and I want Dependency Injection in the project.  I found that parsley and Robotlegs are two popular frameworks for implementing DI in AS3.  Which is the best one among these two?

My main requirements are

1. lightweight
2. minimal learning
3. extensive documentation and active helping community

Answer (score 6):

Both are good. [Robotlegs](http://www.robotlegs.org) has fewer features and a smaller learning curve. [Parsley](http://www.spicefactory.org/parsley/) has more features and a steeper learning curve. Both have good documentation and support.

But they are "application" frameworks. If all you are looking for is Dependency Injection you can try:

- [SwiftSuspenders](http://github.com/tschneidereit/SwiftSuspenders) (the DI library that Robotlegs uses)
- [SpiceLib](http://www.spicefactory.org/parsley/) (the DI library that Parsley uses)

Comment: Just a note, RobotLegs actually uses SwiftSuspenders library for its IoC

Answer (score 5):

Just based on your list RL is the likely choice. Parsley is a "kitchen sink" with tons of functionality. Rl is fairly sparse providing basic DI and messaging tools.

I've written an image gallery example with both frameworks. There are several variations with the Robotlegs version.

http://joelhooks.com/2009/07/14/inversion-of-control-and-dependency-injection-with-flex-using-the-parsley-application-framework-part-2/

http://joelhooks.com/2009/07/17/robotlegs-as3-a-dependency-injection-driven-mvcs-framework-for-flashflex-–-inspired-by-puremvc/

http://joelhooks.com/2010/01/16/robotlegs-image-gallery-example-using-as3-signals-and-the-presentation-model/

http://joelhooks.com/2010/06/16/do-you-need-metadata-as3-robotlegs/

Answer (score 3):

There is no "Best one" when it comes to frameworks.  Many frameworks often use similar design patterns, but have a slightly different implementation of them to accomplish similar goals.

Frameworks are designed to solve problems in development.  First, you need to decide what problems you're trying to solve; then you can evaluate frameworks to see if they will help you solve those problems.  Many times the answer is yes.

In terms of popularity; Robotlegs is the current "Darling" of the Flex Community; but Parsley has barely made a dent.  But, popularity hardly relates to solving the problems specific to your project.

Comment: Don't forget that with "Best one" people often mean state of documentation, community acceptance, how well it's updated. "Best One" is not always about quality of code or best method to do something.

Answer (score 1):

Prove me if I'm wrong, but to me Parsley seems way more unit-tested. As to the learning curve steepness both are quite similar - when focused only on the basic features an experienced Flex developer should be able to pick it up in a matter of a day or two.